# create different rows with knock out js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am using knock out and bootstrap in my project,I have an array of my persons and want to show them in my portfolio page,i want to have one bootstrap row with 3 columns and I use knock out binding,this is my html code:

```
 <div class="row" data-bind="foreach:personarray">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="rowg">
            <a href="#"><img data-bind="attr:{src:Image}" height="250" width="250" class="img-circle img-responsive center-block" /> </a>
            <h3 class="headertext" data-bind="text:Name"></h3>
            <p class="parageraf" data-bind="text:Desc"></p>
            <ul class="list-inline social-buttons ulg">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> </a>
                <li>
                    <a><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i> </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and i fill my personarray in my java script files.
the problem is that when I us F12 i see that there is just one bootstrap row with 6 columns!!! but i want 2 rows and each row has to have 3 columns
i try to put for each binding in different tags but non of them create what i want

here is my JS code:

```
define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {
var title = 'Portfolio';
var PersonID = ko.observable();
var personarray = ko.observableArray([]);
var vm = {
    activate: activate,
    title: title,
    personarray: personarray
};

return vm;

//#region Internal Methods
function activate() {
    logger.log(title + ' View Activated', null, title, true);
    $.getJSON('api/Person/GetPersons', function (result) {

        personarray(result);
    });
return true;
}
//#endregion
 });
```

and my rowg class just contains padding and text alignment.
can any one help me
thank you

Comment: Please share some js code too..

Comment: define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {
    var title = 'Portfolio';
    var PersonID = ko.observable();
    var personarray = ko.observableArray([]);
    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        title: title,
        personarray: personarray
    };

    return vm;

    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate() {
        logger.log(title + ' View Activated', null, title, true);
        $.getJSON('api/Person/GetPersons', function (result) {

            personarray(result);
        });
    return true;
    }
    //#endregion
});

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if` that checks if you are on the 3rd element of the array and create a new row in that case.

To check if it's the 3rd element you can use (inside the foreach):

```
$index() % 3 == 0
```

Here is an example you can use to solve your problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/aq66405h/

Comment: thank you so much but if i do like this does it have any effects on being responsive?I mean do I have to check number of columns for each view port?

Comment: Really depends on your needs, this feature you asked for will create separate rows instead of using pure bootstrap responsiveness.